# How to pass a value to read input before being prompted?

Tags: shell

I have shell script prompting an answer y/n. at the prompt before giving input, I used control-c signal which calls Signal Handling function. In Signal Handling function there is a prompt "q" to exit or "y" and "y" should be used with the FIRST read prompt.

I tried to `(( echo "y" | read ))` but didn't work

```
      ==========================================
           This is part of my script:

IntHandle ()

{ 
   echo -e "\nUse 'q' to quit "
   read var1 
   if [[ $var1 == q ]]
   then
        exit 1
   else
        echo "y" | read ----->here I need "y" to be an input to read prompt 
                             directly and being saved in "ans" variable in 
                             main body where I used control-c 
   fi
 }


trap 'IntHandle' SIGINT
read -p "no valid user id entered, new user ids? [y\n]: " ans ----> here 
                                  used control-c signal before give y/n to ans
if [[ $ans == "y" ]]
then 
     read -p " username :" name
fi
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

================

output should be like below:

no valid user id entered, new user ids? [y\n]: #control-c entered

' Use 'q' to quit '   y ------> here "y" entered rather "q" in Siganl Handeling 
                          function then it is saved in "ans" variable which gets 
                           the condition true to prompt a username.

usernames: Larry -----> the name which is entered after true condition.
.
.
.

Comment: 4-spaces *before* each line of the script so that it formats properly. Enclose inline code between backticks (e.g. `'\`'`) to `format as code` in a paragraph. `"============================"` and `"In main body of my script:"` are not part of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
echo "y" | read
```

Try:

```
ans=y
```

The definition of the trap function needs to be made before the trap is triggered. So I would move it to the top of the file.

When the function finishes, control is returned to the `read` statement that was interrupted by the Ctrl-C. So what I would do instead of `echo "y" | read` or `ans=y` is to reissue the original prompt:

```
IntHandle ()
{ 
  echo -e "\nUse 'q' to quit "
  read var1 
  if [[ $var1 == q ]]
  then
       exit 1
  else
       echo -n 'no valid user id entered, new user ids? [y\n]: '
  fi
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the function just has to be defined before the trap is *triggered*, but since you don't know when that might be, it's definitely safer to make sure the function is already defined.

Comment: But that will duplicate the prompt  "no valid user id entered, new user ids? [y\n]: "  which I can't delete the original one because it is required for if condition I used. Regarding the set of the function, I used it at the beginning of my script but here I put it late for clarification.

Comment: @RedHat: It will only duplicate the prompt if the user presses Ctrl-C _and_ enters something other than "q" at the quit prompt. You should _not_ delete the first `read` and its prompt. As far as the clarification goes, I'm assuming you mean that's for the purpose of posting your question. If that's so, instead of clarifying, it creates confusion since it causes the script to not work in a way that's different from the problem that you're trying to solve and if you post code that's different from what you're actually using it might lead to getting answers that aren't applicable.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. First, I edited my posted code to put the function at the beginning. But, when  I use control -c signal it should not duplicate the prompt message as that I have been asked to do. Rather than that, when I enter "y" I should get to prompt "username" directly. Thanks for your help attempts